# Unity Cache Delete File (Delete AssetBundle)

Tags: c#, unity3d, кэширование

Как удалить определенный файл из Кэша в Юнити?
Ситуация такая: у меня есть AssetBundle, который мне нужно постоянно удалять и загружать на его место новый.

Метод `Caching.ClearCachedVersion()` не работает должный образом, ибо проблема с файлом Манифестом(если кто-то уже делал скиньте кусок кода с подробной инструкцией).

Метод `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload()`, где в параметры должны указать номер версии не удаляет из Кэша старую версию АссетБандла, а лишь только загружает новый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить вопрос (спустя долгих мучений) таким образом:
Создать свой собственный Кэш и залить туда файлы которые будут меняться, а неизменные АссетБандлы загружать в другой созданный Кэш

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("Cache1");
Caching.AddCache("Cache1"); 
Cache c1 = Caching.GetCacheByPath("Cache1");
Caching.currentCacheForWriting = c1;
```

Comment: если вы решили свою проблему сами - отметьте ответ как верный